# shifted errorbar plot wrt hist plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Could someone help me figure out as to why error bars are shifted a bit as compared to line histogram? I wish to have error bars at the center of each bar of line histogram.

```
#mc and data are two dataframes.
norm = np.empty_like(mc['variable'])
bins=np.linspace(0,30,101)
binw=bins[1]-bins[0]
xc = bins[1:]-binw*0.5

hist_mc_corr,_ = np.histogram(mc['variable'].values, density=False, weights=mc['weight_mc'].values, bins=bins) 
hist_data,_ =  np.histogram(data['variable'].values, density=False, weights=data['weight_data'].values, bins=bins)

norm.fill(hist_data.sum()/hist_mc_corr.sum() )

plt.hist(mc['variable'], bins=100, range=(0, 30),histtype='step', weights=norm*mc['weight_mc'],)
(_, caps, _) = plt.errorbar(xc+binw*0.5, hist_data,ls='None', yerr=np.sqrt(hist_data), xerr=np.ones_like(hist_data)*binw*0.5,  
 color='black', label='data', marker='.')
for cap in caps:
    cap.set_markeredgewidth(0)
```

[image]

While it should look like (except I do not want to fill histogram with color.)

[image]

Many thanks!

Comment: I guess you would benefoit from providing a [mcve].

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The solution below worked! Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your errorbars are shifted to the right, because you explicitely do so in

```
... plt.errorbar(xc+binw*0.5, ...
```

by adding `binw*0.5` to `xc`.

```
bins[:10]
array([ 0. ,  0.3,  0.6,  0.9,  1.2,  1.5,  1.8,  2.1,  2.4,  2.7])

xc[:10]
array([ 0.15,  0.45,  0.75,  1.05,  1.35,  1.65,  1.95,  2.25,  2.55,  2.85])

(xc+binw*0.5)[:10]
array([ 0.3,  0.6,  0.9,  1.2,  1.5,  1.8,  2.1,  2.4,  2.7,  3. ])
```

By default, `plt.hist` plots the bars (or the steps in your case) centered between the bin edges, so you want your errorbars at `xc`:

```
... plt.errorbar(xc, ...
```